# Interpolation in PyLab

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, scipy

I have two arrays `x`, `y` with coordinates of a function.

Example:

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
y=[0,1,5,20,30,32]
```

`pylab.plot(x,y)` shows me a smooth function for this.

Is there a way to get the `x`-Value for `y=3`?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `numpy.interp` for this.

e.g.:

```
numpy.interp(3.,y,x)  #1.5
```

Note that this only works since your y values are monotonic.  If your y-values aren't monotonic, there is no guarantee that your mapping of y->x is unique.